# Saved dataframe as file in a directory does not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, python-2.7, path

I tried to save a dataframe in a directory I created but It is not working. The directory and file are created but not on the same directory.

I run a script exec.py which is supposed to used a script from dir1, then  create dir3 to write a new file inside but the newly created file appears in the repertory of the module and the dir3 is created in dir1

before

```
Module___
         dir1___
             script.py
         dir2
         exec.py
```

after

```
Module___
         dir1___
                script1.py
                dir3
         dir2
         exec.py
         file.xlsx
```

What I want :

```
Module___
         dir1___
                script1.py
        
         dir2
         dir3___
                 file.xlsx
         exec.py
```

code

```
def write_filteredData_toExit(dataframe, FichierNom):
   
   path_result = '../../dir3'
   if not os.path.exists(path_result):
       os.makedirs(path_result)

   dataframe['Etiquette_finale'] = dataframe['Etiquette_valide'].map({0: 'Frein', 1: 'Motivation', 2: 'condition'})

   dataframe.to_excel(os.path.join(path_result,'{}.xlsx'.format(FichierNom)))
   print('DataFrame is written to Excel File successfully at', path_result)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call the to_excel, you are just joining a string path_result which is having relative path two levels above, so it will not resolve properly. Instead using the current Path , frame the dir path, like so :

`savetoPath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'../../dir3'))`
and then use the savetoPath in your join() when calling to_excel.